# answer later feature

Tags: discussion, answers

Often, I don't want to save a question as favorite, but I do want to keep track of it, as I might want to answer when I have more availability.

What is the best way to do this, or could/should this be a feature request?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the favorite functionality, it is quite great for this!

Comment: because I want to save those amazing life-saving questions/answers and they are starting to pile up :p

Comment: Hehe I can understand that, but as soon as you have answered a question you can unmark it as a favorite again :)

Comment: I guess that is (one) valid answer to this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the favorite functionality for this actually.

When I see a question I want to answer, but lacks the time to do so, I mark them as favorites.

Later, when I revisit the questions (and hopefully answered..) I unmark them as favorites to avoid them drowning the questions I have marked as favorites for other reasons.